# Change Alt+Right-Mouse Drag for resizing window

Tags: xfce, resize, shortcut-keys

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse-Right-button for resizing window (xfce DE). But it's not convenient to do so with a touchpad.

I want to bind this combination to other key combination without pressing right mouse button. For example to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> and then just moving cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Window Manager Preferences in xfce:

`All Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard Tab`

Select the **Resize window** action and double click, then press your preferred keyboard shortcut and it's done. Now you can press your selected key combination and move your cursor afterwards to resize the current window.

[Window Manager preferences with custom Resize window keyboard shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELDgX.png)

Comment: Later Ubuntu versions have it under `Settings > Devices > Keyboard`, but the name of the shortcut is the same: `Resize window`.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are separated from windows manager keyboard shortcuts in xfce/xfwm. Since OP is using xfce I suppose regular Ubuntu/Gnome settings location won't apply tho his/her problem.

Comment: I found in ubuntu 20.04, in Unity settings - Keyboard Shortcuts - windows, the default window move is Alt+F7 and window resize is Alt+F8. I think Alt-mouse and Ctrl-mouse is quicker and I'll test if I can change it.

Comment: @ChanKim But this is an xfce question

Comment: @MarcoR. right I forgot.  But for gnome, I changed the window move, window resize to Alt-F1 and Alt-F2 and this is more convenient than the default (because I can press alt-F1 or alt-F2 with just the left hand  so I can do it with the mouse kept in right hand)

Comment: Thanks! This was breaking text column selection for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Window Manager Tweaks** > **Accessibility** > **Key used to grab and move windows** => Change ***Alt*** to something else

To print the relevant property:

```
cat ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml | grep easy_click
```

Or

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/easy_click
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it's also convenient to use
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>R</kbd> to resize windows.